# String return value in recursive function in java

Tags: java, string, recursion, return, substring

So I'm practicing java currently, I'm a beginner and I try to explain all the examples that I code so I can understand how and why things are like that. I understand the concept of recursion but I came across this problem when I tried to explain this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class JavaExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str;
        System.out.println("Enter your username: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        str = scanner.nextLine();
        scanner.close();
        String reversed = reverseString(str);
        System.out.println("The reversed string is: " + reversed);
    }

    public static String reverseString(String str)
    {
        if (str.isEmpty())
            return str;
        //Calling Function Recursively
        return reverseString(str.substring(1)) + str.charAt(0);
    }
}
```

With my knowledge so far about recursion, I tried to explain it like this.
Let's have for example a string "Petar":

```
reverseString(etar)+P
reverseString((tar)+etar)+P
reverseString((ar)+tar+etar)+P
reverseString((r)+ar+tar+etar)+P
-----------------------------------
r+ar+tar+etar+P
```

I noticed that the right answer is the first character from every individual piece, so I must be close.

Thank you for your time and I'm sorry if I didn't express myself clearly, I'm from Europe (sry bad inglish).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works like this:

```
reverseString("Peter") = 
        reverseString("eter") + P = 
                (reverseString("ter") + e) + P = 
                    ((reverseString("er") + t) + e) + P = 
                        (((reverseString("r") + e) + t) + e) + P = 
                            ((((reverseString("") + r) + e) + t) + e) + P =
                            (((("" + r) + e) + t) + e) + P =
                            ((((r) + e) + t) + e) + P =
                            (((r + e) + t) + e) + P = 
                            (((re) + t) + e) + P = 
                            ((re + t) + e) + P = 
                            ((ret) + e) + P = 
                            (ret + e) + P = 
                            (rete) + P = 
                            rete + P = 
                            reteP
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the broken down answer. Really appreciate the time and effort. It's all clear now!

Answer (score 1):

You doing good for first line `reverseString(etar)+P` you keep at the end only the *first char**, just do the same for next lines

- put first char at the end
- send the rest to the method

```
reverseString(etar)+P
reverseString(tar) +e+P
reverseString(ar)  +t+e+P
reverseString(r)   +a+t+e+P
reverseString('')  +r+a+t+e+P // stops when empty string is passed
```

Comment: I thought it was like: (reverseString(str.substring(1))) + str.charAt(0), aka I thought that the method was calling only for the str.substring(1). But thank for the answer it helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

It should become clear when start with the simplest possible example: the empty string and string of size 1. Then substituting arguments of each call, to make it more obvious:

```
// string.isEmpty() is true, so the empty string is returned immediately
reverse("")  -> "" 
reverse("a") -> reverse("") + 'a' -> ("") + 'a' -> "a"
```

These are the trivial examples, let's try it with longer strings:

```
reverse("ab")  -> reverse("b") + 'a'
reverse("abc") -> reverse("bc") + 'a'
               -> (reverse("c") + 'b') + 'a'
               -> ((reverse("") + 'c') + 'b') + 'a'
               -> ((("") + 'c') + 'b') + 'a'
               -> "cba"
```

The general pattern should be clear now. For the sake of completeness, let's manually "unroll" the recursive calls for a 4 character string:

```
reverse("abcd") -> reverse("bcd") + 'a'
                -> (reverse("cd") + 'b') + 'a'
                -> ((reverse("d") + 'c') + 'b') + 'a'
                -> (((reverse("") + 'd') + 'c') + 'b') + 'a'
                -> (((("") + 'd') + 'c') + 'b') + 'a'
                -> "dcba"
```

Comment: Oh, it's clear now. I was wrong because I thought that the method was self calling only with the str.substring(1) portion, aka (reverseString(str.substring(1))) + str.charAt(0). Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: @PetarBrdaroski it is. The recursive call is only passed the "tail" of the string. The head is appended after the recursive call returns

Answer (score 1):

You got the first call right but the others were a bit off. In each recursive call you return the the string with the first character at the end instead of the begining. Thus, the recursion looks something like this:

```
reverseString("Petar")
return reverseString("etar") + "P"
return reverseString("tar") + "e"
return reverseString("ar") + "t"
return reverseString("r") + "a"
return reverseString("") + "r"
return ""
```

So the function will return: (((((("")+"r")+"a")+"t")+"e")+"P"), which is "rateP".

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, I appreciate the time!

Answer (score 0):

On your example when your function reaches only one character like
Peter when it becomes only "P"
and the string is not empty you call

```
substring(1)
```

Which calls an index out of the range while the string only have P on index 0 and none on index 1
You have to put a base case that checks if the string length is equal to 1 or less